# A card draw problem concerning Coupon collector's problem

Tags: probability, coupon-collector

I got a problem from my probability test. It is:
There are 21 cards labeled with each of A, B, C, 1, 2, . . . , 9. For each of A, B, C, there is one card labeled with it, and for each of 1, 2, . . . , 9, there are two cards labeled with it. Consider to repeat trials each of which is “to draw one from 21 cards uniformly at random.” 
Answer the following questions.
(1) Let X denote the number of trials repeated until any one of A, B, C appears. Find the expectation of X.
(2) Let Y denote the number of trials repeated until each of A, B, C appears at least once. Find the expectation of Y.
(3) Let Z denote the number of trials repeated until each of 1, 2, . . . , 9 appears at least once. Please tell which is greater, the expectation of Z or the expectation of Y, and also explain your reason.
(4) Let P denote the probability that each of A, B, C appears at least once after n trials. Describe P using n.

I know situation (1) is a geometric distribution, through it is a little complex to calculate E(X), I could do that. But from (2), I cannot image how to write its probability formula, I searched the Wiki and know it seems like a variation of Coupon collector's problem. By intuition, I think it should be 21+21+21=63 times? and (3) should be (21/2)*9=94.5?

Could you give me some hints and your thoughts on this problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(1)$ Indeed geometric distribution where the number of trials needed to arrive at a success are counted. Here the parameter is $p=\frac3{21}$ so that $\mathbb EX=\frac1p=\frac{21}3=7$.

$(2)$ Here we could write $Y=Y_1+Y_2+Y_3$ where $Y_1$ is the same as $X$ in $(1)$, $Y_2$ has geometric distribution with parameter $p=\frac2{21}$ (if e.g. the first success is a draw of card $A$ then for reaching the second success we need to draw $B$ or $C$ because drawing $A$ is in that case not a success anymore) and $Y_3$ has geometric distribution with parameter $p=\frac1{21}$. With linearity of expectation we find: $$\mathbb EY=\mathbb EY_1+\mathbb EY_2+\mathbb EY_3=\frac{21}3+\frac{21}2+\frac{21}1$$

$(3)$ As in $(2)$ you could write here $Z=Z_1+\cdots+Z_9$ (caution: the index does not correspond with the label but with chronology of successes) and calculate $\mathbb EZ$ the same way as done in $(2)$. Then you can of course compare this with $\mathbb EY$ and answer the question. You will find that $\mathbb EY>\mathbb EZ$ and actually you are not asked explicitly to find $\mathbb EZ$ but to just to answer and "explain your reason" (I leave that upto you).

$(4)$ This can expressed as $P(Y\leq n)$.

Comment: Dear @drhab, thank you for answering my question! For (3), so far it seems that I only know to calculate E(Z) first, then compare with E(Y) to see which is bigger ... For (4), though your hint is already clear, but I am still a little bit confused... I have tried to write it:  $P(Y\leq N)=\frac3{21}\times\frac2{21}\times\frac1{21}\times{\textstyle\binom n4\left(1-{\displaystyle\frac1{21}}\right)}^{n-3}$ but it seems not right, could you please teach me for it?

Comment: Thank you, I know what you mean. But don't we need to consider that...em...  like we guarantee n is big enough, and when we finally have drawn C, but before that we have already draw B 3 times and A 5 times? (just an example), from what you have written, it seems that this formula could not reflect this situation... and what if $n\geq21$ ? For this question is a put-back-and-draw experiment.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Neglect my former comment (i will delete it). I was thinking wrongly of drawing cards without replacement there.

Comment: I suspect there is no nice form for $P(Y\leq n)$. Of course it equals $P(Y_1+Y_2+Y_3\leq n)$ where the $Y_i$ are independent random variables that have geometrical distribution with distinct parameters. But that is quite hard to get and looking at coupon collector problem on internet you will rarely find something about probability instead of expectation. In what context is this asked? Could it not be that "$P(Y\leq n)$" in that context on its own is enough already as a description?

Answer (score 1):

1. The probability $p$ of any one of $A$, $B$ or $C$ appearing equals $p = \frac{3}{21} = \frac{1}{7}$. This is indeed a geometric distribution, so we find: $$E(X) = \frac{1}{p} = 7$$
2. The probability of $A$ occurring equals $\frac{1}{21}$, and the same is true for $B$ and $C$. We cannot simply multiply 21 by 3, though, because we could get a $B$ or $C$ while looking for $A$. Rather, look at it this way. First, we need to find one of the letters, with probability $\frac{3}{21} = \frac{1}{7}$. As soon as we have found one, we need to get one of the two remaining letters with probability $\frac{2}{21}$. Then, finally, we need to get the last remaining letter with probability $\frac{1}{21}$. We thus find: $$E(Y) = \frac{21}{3} + \frac{21}{2} + \frac{21}{1} = 38.5$$

Can you apply a similar reasoning to questions $3$ and $4$?

Comment: Thank you for your answer @jvdhooft, by using your thoughts I know how to solve Q3. But for Q4... though I know how it works under n rounds experiment this time, I am still a little bit confused for writing the probability formula, for the situations seems too complex ... like when we find an A then the failure P changed?... I do not know, could you tell me about Q4 more clearly, thank you!